# How to check whether the two JButton have same ImageIcon?

Tags: java, swing, icons, compare, jbutton

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if ((button1.getIcon()==button2.getIcon())
        && (button2.getIcon()==button3.getIcon())
        && (button1.getIcon()!=null))
    {
        win=true;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"win");
    }
}
//am not able to perform this action.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `equals()` method instead of comparing using `==`.